# Using group_by to determine median of second column after sorting/filtering for a specific value in first column?

Tags: r, group-by

I have a huge dataset which has been difficult to work with.

I want to find the median of a second column but only based on one value in the first column. I have used this formula to find general medians without specifying/sorting by the specific values in the first column:

`df%>% +group_by(column1)%>%  +summarise(Median=median(colum2))`

However, there is a specific value in column1 I am hoping to sort by and I only want the medians of the second column based on this first value. Would I do something similar to the below?

`df%>% +group_by(column1, specificvalue)%>%  +summarise(Median=median(colum2))`

Is there an easier way to do this? Would it be easier to make a new dataframe based on the specific value in the first column? How would that be done so that I could have column 1 only include the specific value I want but the rest of the rows included so I can easily determine the median of column2?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you need `filter` i.e. `df %>% filter(column1 == "specificvalue") %>% summarise(Median = median(column2))` or just `df %>% summarise(Median = median(column2[column1 == "specificvalue"]))`

Comment: Thank you for the help! Do you also know how to just isolate the column1 specific value to create a new dataset and more quickly run various analyses?

Comment: You need `df1 <- df %>% filter(column1 == "specificvalue")`